# Unable to apply manually edited hunks in git

Tags: git, diff, interactive, staging

I created a test repository with a single text file in it to test interactive staging, manually editing diffs in particular. But no matter what I tried, git always returned error: `patch does not apply`. What's strange is that it does so even when I close the text editor without changing anything. If I just accept the hunk in question without requesting the editor I can commit without a problem.

Just started using Git so it is perfectly possible I messed up something. This is what I did:

```
$ create 'test' directory
$ open shell inside the directory
$ git init
$ create 'newfile.txt' inside the directory
$ git add newfile.txt
$ git commit -m 'first commit'
$ open newfile.txt, add 'line 1', save & exit
$ git add newfile.txt -e
$ editor comes up, close it without any modifications
$ error: newfile.txt: patch does not apply
```

(Using Win 7 64 and Git for Windows.)

Comment: I wonder if this is a line ending issue?  CRLF vs LF?

Comment: I think Ben is right in his guess. Running the commands `mkdir /tmp/test; cd /tmp/test; git init; touch newfile.txt; git add newfile.txt; git commit -m 'first commit'; echo line 1 >> newfile.txt; env EDITOR=gedit git add newfile.txt -e` on my linux system (with git version 1.7.11.4) produces no errors.

Comment: You are right, git config --global core.autocrlf false did the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
```